# Upload user photo using REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, chatter, user

I have a problem uploading a user's photo using the REST API. I follow the documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm#fileUploadExample 
but I get this debug message:

**Response status: Bad Request

Response body: [{"errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD","message":"The file you uploaded doesn't appear to be a valid image."}]**

I'm trying to transfer profile photos between two sandboxes. Other simple REST API scripts work so the problem is not the connection.

below is the code I use:

```
     String endpoint = URL + '/services/data/v59.0/connect/user-profiles/[userId]/photo';

     String boundary = 'a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq';

     String photoDataBase64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII';

     String body = '--' + boundary + '\n';
     body += 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n';
     body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"\n\n';
     body += '{ "cropX" : "0", "cropY" : "0", "cropSize" : "200" }\n';
     body += '--' + boundary + '\n';
     body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload"; filename="myPhoto.jpg"\n';
     body += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1\n\n';
     body += photoDataBase64 + '\n';
     body += '--' + boundary + '--\n';

     HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
     request.setMethod('POST');
     request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
     request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
     request.setBody(body);

     Http http = new Http();
     HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

     System.debug('Response status: ' + response.getStatus());
     System.debug('Response body: ' + response.getBody());
```

for testing purposes I use this site to convert an image to base64: https://codebeautify.org/image-to-base64-converter

Normally i will use this:

```
        User u = [Select FullPhotoUrl From User where id = :Userinfo.getUserid()];
        PageReference ref = new PageReference(u.FullPhotoUrl);
        Blob b = ref.getContent();
        String photoDataBase64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b);
```

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm#cc_upload_binary_files
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_user_profiles_photo.htm

Comment: yes, the HTTP request body is as in the documentation.

Comment: I've linked a relevant Q&A that should help you out. The binary data you're trying to upload must be in binary format, not base64 encoded. Since Apex doesn't have really great binary support, this means you'll be shuffling your payload between base64 or hex back and forth as you construct the payload.